# SSRS: Split Data into two columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SQL table that has two columns I'm interested in; Event_Time and Event_ID. Event_ID stores the numerical value for a begin and end event (1 for a start and 2 for an end) each event has an associated Event_Time. What I would like to do is to display these rows as columns in an SSRS report:

```
Event_ID     Event_Time
1            5/11/2017 9:50 AM
2            5/11/2017 9:55 AM
```

I'd like to see:

```
Start Time               End Time
5/11/2017 9:50 AM        5/11/2017 9:55 AM
```

Here is what the table looks like:
[image]

EDIT:

To elaborate more, The report will show the data grouped by Container_ID. Currently the report shows this table:

```
Container ID        Event ID          Event Time
17080430-002        1                 5/11/2017 9:50 AM
                    2                 5/11/2017 9:55 AM
```

We'd like to see:

```
Container ID        Start Time               End Time
17080430-002        5/11/2017 9:50 AM        5/11/2017 9:55 AM
```

Edit 2:

So far I've had some luck with this:

```
select t1.Container_ID, t1.Event_Time Start, t2.Event_Time [End]
from (
select Container_ID, Event_Time,
   ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by Container_ID order by Event_Time) EventID
FROM dbo.Custom_EventLog WHERE Event_ID = '1'
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT Container_ID, Event_Time,
   ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by Container_ID order by Event_Time) EventID
from dbo.Custom_EventLog WHERE Event_ID = '2'
) t2
on (t1.Container_ID = t2.Container_ID and t1.EventID = t2.EventID)
```

But the returned table has misaligned times as pictured:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and how is the behavior different from what you expect? Can you show us some code?

Comment: @LewsTherin I've updated the question with code I've tried

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure with that table structure if you can tell what start and end times correspond to the same event (unless there is another column not shown in your question that establishes the relationship).

That being said, you might be able to do something with two sub-queries that filter by the `Event_ID` like:

```
SELECT (SELECT Event_Time FROM tableName WHERE Event_ID = 1) AS [Start Time],
       (SELECT Event_Time FROM tableName WHERE Event_ID = 2) AS [End Time]
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but I get an error saying the subquery returned more than 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is sort of what you are after.  I would solve this issue in SQL rather than SSRS.  Temp table is just for us to actually work with some data.

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#events') is not null drop table #events
create table #events
(
    mainEventId int,
    eventId int,
    Event_Time datetime
)

insert into #events
select 200, 1, '5/11/2017 9:50 AM'
union all select 200, 2, '5/11/2017 9:55 AM'
union all select 300, 1, '5/11/2017 9:50 AM'
union all select 300, 2, '5/11/2017 9:55 AM'

select startTime.mainEventId, startTime.Event_Time, endTime.Event_Time
from #events startTime 
left join #events  as endTime
    on startTime.mainEventId = endTime.mainEventId
    and endTime.eventId = 2
where
    startTime.eventId = 1
```

Comment: This works but it doesn't handle containers that have no end recorded. Is there a way to clean this up, possibly by the Row_ID?

Comment: Oh, sure, just left join the endTime... I will edit the query.

Comment: The times are still misaligned somehow. I think it might be because of how the data is in the table and there may not be away to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely do this in SQL rather than SSRS. Seems to me, you could get away with this by just doing a join - my example below is an inner join, but you can easily mod it to use a left-join (or whatever)

```
select t1.container_id, t1.startTime, t2.endTime
from (select container_id, event_time as startTime from tableName as t1
      where event_id = 1) as t1
join (select container_id, event_time as endTime from tableName as t2
      where event_id = 2) as t2 on t2.container_id = t1.container_id
```

hope that helps.